# In Java, does locking ensure correct order of reads and write to nonvolatile locations

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have a shared object of class:

```
class Shared {
    private int x = 0 ;
    private int y = 0 ;
    private Semaphore s = new Semaphore() ;

    public int readX() {
        s.p() ;
        int x0 = x ;
        s.v() ;
        return x0 ; }

    public void writeX(int x0) {
        s.p() ;
        x = x0 ;
        s.v() ; }

    public int readY() {
        s.p() ;
        int y0 = y ;
        s.v() ;
        return y0 ; }

    public void writeY(int y0) {
        s.p() ;
        y = y0 ;
        s.v() ; } }
```

Here Semaphore is a class that uses *synchronized* methods to provide mutual exclusion.

Now the following actions happen:

- Thread 0 calls o.readX() and finds it to be 0.
- Thread 1 writes 1 to x and then 1 to y using o.writeX(1) ; o.writeY(1) ;
- Thread 0 calls o.readY() getting 1 and then calls o.readX() .

Could thread 0 read from its cache and find that x is 0? Why?

---

EDIT

Here is the Semaphore class

```
class Semaphore {
    private boolean available = true ;

    public synchronized void v() {
        available = true ; notifyAll() ; }

    public synchronized void p() {
        while( !available ) try{ wait() ; } catch(InterruptedException e){} 
        available = false ; }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unanswerable without knowing the semantics of your `Semaphore`, which clearly isn't the one from the JDK. It is also strange that you start by `unlock`ing it, then `lock` it in the end.

Comment: Given that neither `x` nor `y` are declared `volatile`, the answer to your question is "yes". Why: because otherwise the JVM is free to do reordering.

Comment: @fge The JVM is not free to reorder over locks, and OP says the Semaphore methods are synchronized.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I added Semaphore.  Sorry for the poor choice of method names.

Comment: I changed the names to p and v.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to JMM the following sequence is strictly ordered by happens-before relationship and therefore guarantees visibility of change done in the step 1 to reader at step 4:

1. write to x
2. exit from synchronized block guarded by monitor M
3. entering into the synchronized block guarded by monitor M
4. read from x

Write to variable happens-before releasing the monitor, releasing the monitor happens-before acquiring the same monitor and acquiring the monitor happens-before read from variable.

So if `p` and `v` are synchronized then thread 0 will see the change to x.

Comment: Yeah, but is just informal description of what is happening. Formal description using JMM terminology seems to be correct. Anyway I will update the answer.

Comment: Staying correct while using informal language is a skill to hone, but it can be done :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is very helpful.  It's interesting that it doesn't matter what s.p() and s.v() do as long as they synchronize on the same object.

Answer (score 3):

Presenting the actions of your two threads side-by-side:

```
Thread 1                       Thread 2
o.readX(); // 0                o.writeX(1);
o.readY(); // 1                o.writeY(1);
o.readX(); // must be 1
```

There is a strict *happens-before* ordering of any arbitrarily chosen pair of invocations of your `Semaphore` methods because they both go through an acquire-release cycle on the same shared `Semaphore` instance.

We have:

- `o.writeX(1)` by Thread 2 *happens-before* `o.writeY(1)`;
- `o.writeY(1)` by Thread 2 *happens-before* `o.readY() -> 1` by Thread 1;
- `o.readY()` by Thread 1 *happens-before* the second `o.readX()` by Thread 1;
- therefore `o.writeX(1)` by Thread 2 *happens-before* the second `o.readX()` by Thread 1;
- therefore the result of the second `o.readX()` must be 1.